# Keras: Elementwise operation: dot or inner products, numpy.matmul equivalent

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am trying to do elementwise dot operation on axis 3+

```
np.random.seed(10)
a = np.random.randint(0, 5, (2,1,3))  # should also work with
b = np.random.randint(0, 5, (2,3,1))  # higher dim, eg. (2,2,1,3) * (2,2,3,1)
print(a)
print(b)
print()
res = np.dot(a,b)
print(res.shape)
res
```

and I get

```
[[[1 4 0]]

 [[1 3 4]]]
[[[1]
  [0]
  [1]]

 [[2]
  [0]
  [1]]]

(2, 1, 2, 1)
array([[[[1],
         [2]]],


       [[[5],
         [6]]]])
```

but I want

```
[[[1]],
 [[6]]]
```

I tried

```
np.multiply(a,b)
```

which gives `(2,3,3)` which is quite close, so I also tried `(2,3,1)` with `(2,1,3)` thinking that it would perhaps yield `(2,1,1)` but it doesn't change the shape. I expect `(2,1,1)` or simply `(2,)`.

Also, I'm restricted to using Keras Backend functions as this will go right into my loss function. Keras has `.dot()`, `.prod()` equivalents for numpy functions.

How do I do this?

---

UPDATE: `np.matmul()` does what I want:

```
np.matmul(a,b)
(2, 1, 1)
array([[[1]],

       [[6]]])
```

but I still do NOT know how to do this using keras backend dot or multiply.

Comment: Can you briefly explain how you get `[1]` and `[6]`. Currently due to the complex array shape, it is not so evident how these will be the output.

Comment: element wise dot product on `axis=0`. Basically dot applied on last two axes while many such operations are done by having matrices of `(1,3)` and `(3,1)` which is here `(2,3,1)` and `(2,1,3)`

Comment: `np.matmul(a,b)` gives exactly what I want....! But I'm now wondering how I could do this using `keras.backend.idk_what_to_use` :(

Comment: Try this `ans = [sum(a[i].T*b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]`. Of course this is breaking down the problem into 2d array. I am not sure about Keras

Comment: Thanks, but I can't afford to use `for`s, I got `(128, 128)` before that `(1,3)` and `(3,1)`[4d tensors...!] and obviously I can solve this using nested `for`s but I want to take my GPU for a ride, giving some rest to my CPU

Comment: Use tensorflow's `tf.matmul`?